# Is it possible to use dynamic columns multiple times in a select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, lateral-join

I have some complex string replacement and I'm only permitted read-only access.

I'd like to have several columns where each is dependent on the previous column so I can see if my `substring` and `charindex` functions are correct.

Basically this:

```
DECLARE @myvar NVARCHAR(100) = 'ThisIsMyTest'

SELECT REPLACE(@myvar, 'My', 'Our') AS Part1
    ,Part1 + ' added to the end'
```

Where I would want the output of the second column to be:

> `ThisIsOurTest added to the end`

This is an extremely simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish, so I'm looking for the concept. I don't need this answer:

```
SELECT REPLACE(@myvar, 'My', 'Our') as Part1, REPLACE(@myvar, 'My', 'Our') + ' added to the end'
```

as that's what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, one option uses lateral joins. They are handy in this situation, because the "next" join has access to the dataset generated by the previous one(s). Basically, you can put each intermediate computation in a separate (scalar) subquery.

Starting from your simplified example, that would be:

```
select t1.part1, t2.part2
from (values (replace(@myvar, 'My', 'Our'))) t1(part1)
cross apply (values (t1.part1 + ' added to the end')) t2(part2)
```

Comment: This is blowing my mind trying to understand it, but it works and is exactly what I need. I've never seen the `t1(part1)` syntax before or the `(values(...))` used that way before. What is that called so I can google and read more?

Comment: @WilliamYK: the [`cross apply` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a good place to start!